# Centering title in bibliography with abntex2cite

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bibliographies

i need some help.

I'd like to change the title of my bibliography (Referências Bibliográficas), align left to centering, i'm using package abntex2cite to make my citations. My document class is a report. I've been tried to use titlesec package to change that, but didn't work.

Here's a little part of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktoc=all, pdftex, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[alf, abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-emphasize=bf]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}
\include{Capitulo1/Cap1}
\include{Capitulo2/Cap2}
\include{Capitulo3/Cap3}
\bibliography{Referencias}
\end{document}
```

Sorry my poor English. There's a image of what i wanna do bellow.

[image: Referencias Bibliograficas]
Cheers Jean.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is not compilable, since it contains files not available to use (`\include` - statements)

Comment: In addition, `hyperref` should basically be the last package to be included

Comment: Ty Christian for your help. The code \include is just to insert my chapters and the package hyperref isn't last one because a error with the package abntex2cite, abntex2cite package must be insert after hyperref package.

Comment: I did work, just put this code in my preamble. \addto\captionsbrazil{
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\centerline{Refer\^encias Bibliográficas}}
}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments